# How do I use foundry's Anvil..?

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

I've been trying to speed up the time and increase the number of blocks for testing a smart contract I'm writing.

I am not able to use Anvil's commands for this.

I first typed `anvil` in the command line to create a node.

Then tried out this code which returns an error `DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.`

```
    function testTaskExecutesSuccesfullyCorrectly() public {
        anvil_mine(10);
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing on how to use Anvil...?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just start learning foundry, I would guess that within your test function, you should use the VM cheatcodes. In particular, the roll https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/roll.

I think the anvil_mine() should be used as a param when using the anvil cli command.

Answer (score 1):

**Set interval mining with `anvil`:**

1. Initiate an anvil blockchain instance that produces a block every 10 seconds.
   https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/anvil/#mining-modes

```
$ anvil --block-time 10
```

**Use `cast` to toggle interval block mining (with an `anvil` instance running on localhost):**

1. Turn on interval mining:

```bash
$ RPC="http://127.0.0.1:8545"
$ cast rpc evm_setIntervalMining 10 --rpc-url $RPC
null
```

2. Return to auto mining:

```bash
$ cast rpc evm_setAutomine true --rpc-url $RPC
null
```

**Use `cast` to explicitly advance time/blocks with `anvil`'s [supported RPC methods](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/anvil/#supported-rpc-methods) (with an `anvil` instance running on localhost):**

1. Take a snapshot of the current state of the blockchain (save "0x0" for future use).

```bash
$ RPC="http://127.0.0.1:8545"
$ cast rpc evm_snapshot --rpc-url $RPC
"0x0"
```

2. Get current block timestamp.

```bash
$ cast rpc eth_getBlockByNumber "latest" "false" --rpc-url $RPC
{..., timestamp: "0x64460395", ...}
```

3a. Manually mine a single block.

```bash
$ cast rpc evm_mine --rpc-url $RPC
"0x0"

$ cast rpc eth_getBlockByNumber "latest" "false" --rpc-url $RPC
{..., timestamp: "0x64460c86", ...}
```

3b. Manually specify the timestamp to advance.

```bash
$ cast rpc evm_setNextBlockTimestamp 0xeeeeeeee --rpc-url $RPC
null

$ cast rpc evm_mine --rpc-url $RPC
"0x0"

$ cast rpc eth_getBlockByNumber "latest" "false" --rpc-url $RPC
{..., "timestamp":"0xeeeeeeee", ...}
```

4. Return back to original snapshot.

```bash
$ cast rpc evm_revert 0x0 --rpc-url $RPC
true

$ cast rpc eth_getBlockByNumber "latest" "false" --rpc-url $RPC
{..., "timestamp":"0x64460395", ...}
```

**Set time using cheatcodes**

1. Use [vm.warp](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/warp) within test files. I'm not sure how this can be used outside of test files tbh...

Comment: Thanks! That works well :)